# Strict Use in jQuery

Tags: jquery, strict

i am rewriting my jQuery code in `'use strict';` and i am having a lot of issues with my functions.

```
var queue = $(function(start) {
    var rest = [].splice.call(arguments, 1),
                promise = $.Deferred();

    if (start) {
        $.when(start()).then(function () {
            queue.apply(window, rest);
        });
    } 
    else {
        promise.resolve();
    }
    return promise;
});
```

The original function that was working before the 'use strict' was, maybe i reworte it bad.

```
function queue(start) {
var rest = [].splice.call(arguments, 1),
    promise = $.Deferred();

if (start) {
    $.when(start()).then(function () {
        queue.apply(window, rest);
    });
} else {
    promise.resolve();
}
return promise;
```

}

this function return Object has no method apply and i don't know why.

Certainly i need to improve my code and don't know how to start because all works fine, then i use `'use strict'`, and all breaks.
Do i have to rewrite all my code?
It is only a naming convention issue?

Please any help would be very appreciated

Comment: “strict use”? Is that exactly what you wrote? Because the correct string is `"use strict";`.

Comment: hi, sorry, yes i wrote the correct code "use strict" :)

Comment: Where do you define `'use strict'` in your code?

Comment: hi, at the very beginning of my js file i have(function($) {
    "use strict"; // My code })(jQuery);

Comment: @JoseLo It would really help if you included *all* of the relevant code. You could stick it up in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: hi Jezen, it is a big js file of a WP Theme, it has a lot of functions i am trying to rewrite with no luck, anybody could guide me in what really has to be changed to get 'use strict' working?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is not related to "use strict".

```
var queue = $(function(start) { ... })
```

will execute your function and call it with jQuery object as parameter (start). Then inside your function you try to call `queue.apply` which is not a function (as error message say, and i guess that `queue` is undefined).

Maybe you wanted to write :

```
var queue = function() { ... }
```

Comment: hi Mordhak, that is one os the possibilites i have tested but then when i use queue(function(){},function(){}); it tells me that object is not a function referring to queue :(

Comment: hi again, yes i found my problem is not related with the use script, i deleted that line and problem persists. I think it has to be with enclosing all with function($) {// My code })(jQuery);